# The method '>' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why i have this error whereas all variables is iniatialize.

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
>   RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#657cb relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>   User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
>       Scaffold 
>   ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
>   The method '>' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: >(1e-10)
>   User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
>       OrientationBuilder 
>   lib\no_events.dart:31
>   ═══════════════════════

```
class _NoEvents extends State<NoEvents> {
  List<Contributor> contributors = [];
  List<Event> events = [];
  Contributor contributor = new Contributor(1, "XXX");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    contributors.add(contributor);
    Event event1 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime(2019 - 10 - 25), "XXX", "Test1");
    Event event2 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "XXX", "Test2");
    Event event3 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "XXX", "Test3");
    events.add(event1);
    events.add(event2);
    events.add(event3);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('Lille Events'),
      ),
      body: new OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          return new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (var e in events)
                    new Center(
                      child: new Text(e.subject),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try putting the Event() object creations and the List adds into a initState() Method of your state class.

Comment: @Marc 
```
List<Contributor> contributors = [];
  List<Event> events = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    Contributor contributor = new Contributor(1, "Evan");
    contributors.add(contributor);
    Event event1 =
        new Event(1, contributors, DateTime(2019 - 10 - 25), "Lille", "Test1");
    Event event2 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "Lille", "Test2");
    Event event3 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "Lille", "Test3");
    events.add(event1);
    new Calendar(1, events);
    super.initState();
  }
```
i have always this error !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GridView` inside `Column` causes this error. Try to wrap it in `Expanded`

```dart
class _NoEvents extends State<NoEvents> {
  List<Contributor> contributors = [];
  List<Event> events = [];
  Contributor contributor = new Contributor(1, "XXX");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    contributors.add(contributor);
    Event event1 =
        new Event(1, contributors, DateTime(2019 - 10 - 25), "XXX", "Test1");
    Event event2 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "XXX", "Test2");
    Event event3 = new Event(1, contributors, DateTime.now(), "XXX", "Test3");
    events.add(event1);
    events.add(event2);
    events.add(event3);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lille Events'),
      ),
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (var e in events)
                      Center(
                        child: Text(e.subject),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shrinkWrap:true under GridView

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error when trying to place a PageView widget inside a Column. The fix was to wrap the PageView widget in a [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)() widget.

By default the PageView widget doesn't have a fixed size since it depends on the size of its children. Wrapping it in Flexible() solves any overflow issues you might encounter.